# JRuby cannot use the adapter I installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, rvm

I used rvm to install jruby (1.5.6) and installed all my gems just fine. I can run simple rails tasks like

script/runner 'puts 1'

and the output is fine. AS SOON as I hit the database I get an error. I have uninstalled/reinstalled the activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter gem, Jruby, rvm, JAVA_JDK. I have set the JRUBY_HOME and JAVA_HOME correctly, but it seems like nothing works.

Any thoughts?

As far as I know, I have Java JDK 1.6.0 and 1.5.0 installed. IT is currently pointed to 1.6.0. But since all the other gems installed correctly, I am assuming this is something else entirely.

I am on EC2 with Ubuntu 10.04 (64 bit)

Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM works great!

nohup: ignoring input
/opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:76:in `establish_connection': Please install the jdbcmysql adapter:`gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter`(no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/jdbcmysql_adapter) (RuntimeError)
    from /opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in`establish_connection'
    from /opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
    from /opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:438:in`initialize_database'
    from /opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:141:in `process'
    from /opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in`run'
    from /home/tesmar/rails/statsheet/config/environment.rb:19
    from /home/tesmar/rails/statsheet/config/environment.rb:39:in `require'
    from /opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/runner.rb:39
    from /opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/runner.rb:3:in`require'
    from script/runner:3

Comment: I should add that the database.yml points to the right adapter.

Comment: I should also add that I don't understand how voting works around here. For ex: I voted down Dex's answer to -1 while voting up Mark's. Now dex shows 0 and Mark shows the appropriate 1. Does my vote not count?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to download the JAR file, after copying manually all the rb files into the active record gem (the rb files from the activerecord-jdbcmysql and activerecord-jdbc gems). I then put the JAR file in the /opt/jruby/lib directory and it works! Woohoo!

Comment: I still maintain that there is something odd about your environment. The gem install *should* work without copying .rb files around.

Comment: That is possible, but I followed the RVM instructions exactly. I can provide an ENV dump if necessary (or if you think it would be helpful), but most other things work well (ruby 1.9 and system ruby, for ex.)

Comment: You mentioned I ha d to download the JAR file? Could you please help understanding which JAR file and also the exact steps that you executed to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you need to install the `activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` gem.

It is possible that your execution environment is different from your rvm environment. I've seen this happen with IDEs such as NetBeans.

Comment: I did. using JRUBY. It is listed as installed.

Comment: both jruby -S gem list and gem list. since rvm symlinks gem to the jruby version, it ends up with the same result.

Comment: Are you using an IDE like NetBeans? Your execution environment may not be the same as your rvm environment.

Comment: You know, it's poor form to vote down answers before you find a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi Mark, I appreciate the advice; however his advice did not relate to my problem. I am not having trouble with my database.yml, but rather rails not finding a gem that I have already installed.

Comment: I am not using netbeans, just Ubuntu 10.04 + VIM. I even copied the gem files into the ActiveDirectory gem and that error went way, only to be replaced by the error "cannot find Java class com.mysql" So then it becomes a Java problem. Where is the gem supposed to install the Java class for the mysql adapter?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to download the JAR file, after copying manually all the rb files into the active record gem (the rb files from the activerecord-jdbcmysql and activerecord-jdbc gems). I then put the JAR file in the /opt/jruby/lib directory and it works! Woohoo!

Comment: I went ahead and answered the question myself, but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

How do your gemfile look like?

Mine looks like this and work:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.4'


platforms :ruby do
  gem 'mysql2'
end

platforms :jruby do
  gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
  gem 'jdbc-mysql', :require => false
end
```

Comment: No idea, it was just copy-pasted. But if I were to guess, I'd guess that the jdbc-mysql-gem doesn't provide a 'require jdbc-mysql'

Answer (score 0):

If you are going back and forth between jRuby and MRI, you can add something like this to your Gemfile too:

```
if defined?(JRUBY_VERSION)
   gem 'jdbc-mysql'
   gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
   gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'
   gem 'warbler'
else
   gem 'mysql'
   gem 'mongrel'
end
```

Then, in your database.yml add something like this:

```
development:

    adapter: <%= defined?(JRUBY_VERSION) ? 'jdbcmysql' : 'mysql' %>
```

Comment: Thank you Dex, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: If you used RVM 1.9.2 first, and then tried to use jRuby, you'll need to delete your Gemfile.lock too and re-run `bundle install`. Also, if you're using rvm, I had to create a separate gemset before running bundler.

Comment: When you run the commands, it's best to run them using `jruby -S` too.

Comment: what do you mean by a separate gemset? I used JRuby first, then 1.9.2. This also happens when I install JRUby normally (without RVM) and use jruby -S for all my commands. This one really has me baffled.

Comment: Thank you Dex for your suggestions. There are indeed separate gemsets, but the problem I discovered is below.